# Android Screenshot Capturing

Tags: android, kotlin, mobile-development

I am new to android development and Kotlin. I am trying to implement a feature that takes a screenshot when there is an issue in the application and uploads the screenshot to a server.
I am currently writing a function that uses DrawingCache and saves the view to a bitmap image. Other than this approach, is there a better way to do this? I was wondering whether there is a way to use the Android OS level screenshot capturing mechanism for this?

Comment: check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2661536/how-to-programmatically-take-a-screenshot-on-android

Comment: `that takes a screenshot when there is an issue in the application` i'm not even sure if this would work, if your app isn't responding, would it even succeed in achieving this ? and what would a screenshot actually help in that case ?

Comment: @a_local_nobody I have implemented the code in a way such in case of any exception, catch it and run the screenshot taking function. For now, it is good for my usecase. should check with your opinion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. You should only have a screen of your own views, and not other apps nor system status bar. If that is possible, it is a security issue with Android and Google should forbid it.